# example of a monotone non-continuous map.

Tags: continuity, lattice-orders, fixed-point-theorems

Let me start by defining some terminology to be sure I made no errors there. Parts of this are translated freely from my mother tongue so feel free to correct terminology or the definitions themselves if needed.

> **Complete lattice**
>   A partially ordered set in which all subsets have both a supremum and an infimum.
>
> **Monotonic map**
>   Let $L, \leq$ be a partially ordered set. A map $T : L \mapsto L$ is called monotonic if $x \leq y$ implies that $T(x) \leq T(y)$.
>
> **Directed set**
>   Let $X$ be an arbitrary subset of a partially ordered set. $X$ is directed if and only if each finite subset of $X$ has an upper bound **in** X.
>
> **Continuous map**
>   A map $T : L \mapsto L$ over a complete lattice $L, \leq$ is called a continuous map, if $T(sup(X)) = sup(T(X))$ for every directed subset $X$ of $L$.
>   $T(X)$ is defined as $T(X) = \{T(x) | x \in X \}$

Now it can be shown that for a map $T  : L \mapsto L$ over a complete lattice $L,\leq$

> $T$ is continuous $\implies$ $T$ is monotonic

However the other way round is not true.
Example:

The map
$f : [0,1] \mapsto [0,1] : x \mapsto 
\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{2}x & 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2} \\
      \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1 
   \end{cases}
$

over a complete lattice $[0,1],\leq$ is monotonic, but not continuous.

How can one show that $f$ is not continuous using the definitions above? I figure the discontinuity will be at $x = \frac{1}{2}$ but I cannot find how to prove this. I've tried taking several subsets of $[0,1]$ and tried to find a contradiction, without success.

Anyone wants to shine a light on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say *$X$ is directed if and only if each finite subset of $X$ has an upper bound **in** $X$.* Do you mean to specify finite subsets?  If not, then what is an example of and $X$ that is *not* directed?

Comment: By a finite subset I mean something like $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ should I use the term *bounded* instead?
$[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is directed. $[0,1[ \subset \mathbb{R}$ is not. (Over a complete lattice $\leq$, that is.)

Comment: @Auberon No, you don't mean that. If anything you want to abandon the 'complete lattice' from the definition. I think it's standard to define it for posets.

Comment: @GitGud I think I get it, thanks

Comment: @Omnomnomnom My example was unnecessarily complicated, so I deleted it. The same idea works with $X=\{a,b\}$ in the following diagram. $\begin{array}{ccc} & & c\\\ &\nearrow&\uparrow\\a& & b\end{array}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example: in this case, we can take $X = (0,1/2)$.  Verify that this is a directed subset of $[0,1]$.

Note that
$$
T(\sup(X)) = T(1/2) = 3/4 \neq \sup(T(x)) = \sup(0,1/4) = 1/4
$$

Comment: I've tried a similar approach but: why is $T(1/2) = 1/4$ and not $= 3/4$?

Comment: Check your definition: $1/2 \leq 1/2 \leq 1$, so $T(1/2) = 1/2(1/2) + 1/2$.

Comment: I should've clarified that I meant the $T(1/2)$ on the right hand side of the $\neq$. You say $sup(T(X)) = sup(T(0), T(1/2)) = sup(0, 1/4) = 1/4$. Why is $T(1/2) = 1/4$ and not $= 3/4$ like you just implied in your comment?

Comment: I am not implying that $T(1/2) = 1/4$.  I *am* implying that
$$
\sup_{x \in (0,1/2)}T(x) = 1/4
$$
This is quite a different statement.

Comment: Why is that true? If you pop in $x = \frac{1}{2}$ in $f$, $\frac{3}{4}$ rolls out, am I not right? Apparently this is the essence of my problem. Sorry if I sound confused.

Comment: But $x = 1/2 \notin (0,1/2)$

Comment: I see, I was confused by the bracket notation. I'm used to write $]0,\frac{1}{2}[$ instead of $(0,\frac{1}{2})$. Now, I don't think $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ is a directed set over $\leq$ because it does not have an upper bound $\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: But it is a directed set.  Consider any **finite** sequence.

Comment: Oh right I see. So I could rewrite your equation $\sup_{x\in(0,\frac{1}{2})}T(x) = \frac{1}{4}$ as $\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}} T(x) = \frac{1}{4}$? Or at least think about it that way?

Comment: About my comment above, the limit mentioned is approached from the left.

Comment: You can certainly think about it that way.

Comment: Thank you. Now I can finally continue. Appreciated.